How to update Azure WebApp PHP version to 8.3.6
I am trying to update Azure WebApp to higher PHP versions.
I can do it with major and minor version 8.0-8.3, but i cannot change the versions after.
Any ideas?

Have you tried updating using Azure CLI?

Use --linux-fx-version  and update it to the required version.

As 8.3.6 version is not available , you need to download and install it from SSH

I tried to do it with the CLI using the command, but you cannot change the subversions there. Even if I type PHP 8.3.6 the subversion still stays at 8.3.4
I will try to do it through SSH and we will see.

Yes,to update subversions, we need to do it from SSH by downloading the version.Refer this SOThread for reference.

Even Iam trying from my end.Will let you know if it works for me.

I could not do it, a lot of commands are not found and I cannot use apt-get

Can you please share what you have tried ?
